# Maui Cluster Scheduler: reporting

Tags: linux, cluster-computing, distributed-computing, job-scheduling

I need to generate report that contains detailed information about all task that were distributed by Maui.

Answer (score 0):

You can access historical workload data in `$MAUIHOMEDIR/stats/MM_DD_YYYY` files, and you can create your own scripts to generate reports from the raw data. These historical event files are written in plain/flat text format. Maui has a `showstats` command, but this will only use historical statistic summaries loaded from the checkpoint file.

Comment: Additionally: if you are using Torque as your resource manager you can access batch job accounting records in `TORQUE_HOME/server_priv/accounting/YYYYMMDD`. You may find additional information there to supplement what Maui has provided.

Comment: You might be able to build something in conjunction with a tool like logstash. I'd suggest you pose that question to the mauiusers and/or torqueusers user lists. :-)